# Is a Postgresql UNLOGGED table completely lost on process crash?

Tags: postgresql, crash, unlogged-tables

I use UNLOGGED tables for a few very large tables in a data warehouse style application.

Until recently, I understood UNLOGGED to mean “won’t write to the WAL” - which in turn means that *recent* changes maybe lost on a process crash / unclean termination, and that there will be no replication

Maybe I’m misunderstanding the language in the documentation (or maybe I’m not) but when I read the documentation recently, I understood it to mean the *entire* table will be truncated on an unclean exit. Is that right?

The question is, ***on an unclean exit will the entire table will be TRUNCATEd (per the meaning of TRUNCATE in PostgreSQL) or does it mean truncated as in the everyday use- the end will abruptly terminate, only the most recent rows lost, due to there being no WAL***

Surely it myst be the latter? Being completely TRUNCATEd makes no sense to me; if I have an UNLOGGED table with a year’s worth of data, and today the postgres process goes down, why would it destroy the entire contents of the table?

Or am I misunderstanding and it’s only recent changes (that would normally be restorable via WAL or similarly, by a spare) that would be lost?

The blurb from the official PostgreSQL documentation is as follows, the bit about truncation us what I’m referring to:

> If specified, the table is created as an unlogged table. Data written to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log (see Chapter 30), which makes them considerably faster than ordinary tables. However, they are not crash-safe: an unlogged table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown.

I’m not sure how I never noticed this language but it has me somewhat alarmed. Losing the most recent few days worth of data isn’t a problem for my use, but to have to restore the entire table (~60GB worth of data per-table) from the backups I keep (non-WAL backups, obviously) due to a simple process crash is alarming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the table will be empty after crash recovery. There is no other way to ensure consistency.

One thing you can do is to regularly backup the unlogged table with `pg_dump`.

Comment: Yikes, thank you for confirming